# Wrong value in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I got a problem in for loop

```
var a={ name:""};
var nameList=['jack','luck'];
var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<nameList.length;i++){
   a.name=nameList[i];
   data.push(a);
}
console.log(data) //output [Object { name="luck"}, Object { name="luck"}]
```

which I want the data is [Object { name="jack"}, Object { name="luck"}].

And when I changed code to `data.push({name:nameList[i]})` and `data[i] = {name:nameList[i]}` in the loop, they both return the correct value I expect.

Can anyone tell me what's the difference there?

Answer (score 4):

You've only got one object, and you're repeatedly changing its name, and pushing a reference to it onto the array. This is how variables work in JavaScript; copying is done by value, and the value for variables holding objects is a *reference* to the object.

You need to make a new object each iteration.

```
for(var i=0;i<nameList.length;i++){
   a = { name: nameList[i] }
   data.push(a);
}
```

Comment: so you mean a.name=nameList[i] is making nameList[i] as a reference to a.name?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `a` always holds the same object. When you use `data.push(a)`, you're putting a reference to `a` into your array. It's the **same object** the next iteration, when you overwrite its name.

Answer (score 4):

You are pushing the same object over and over into your array and each time you change the `name` property, you are just changing it on the same object every time.  You would need to create a new copy of the object each time so each one is different.  You can do that without even using an intermediate variable like this:

```
var nameList = ['jack','luck'];
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
   data.push({name: nameList[i]});    // creates a new object each time thru the loop
}
```

or, if you want the intermediate object (for other reasons - not necessary for the code you've shown), it would work like this:

```
var nameList = ['jack','luck'];
var data = [], a;
for(var i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++){
   a = {};
   a.name = nameList[i];
   data.push(a);
}
```

Note, how `a` is assigned a new object each time through the loop so that you are creating and pushing into the array a new object each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a` in both array elements. It's the same object. The second time you change the name, you are changing it for both.